# decltype in template causes compilation failure without instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I need some help in understanding why the code below fails to compile on VC2012 but compiles fine in VC2013? Is there a way to make it work on VC2012 since that is the compiler available for our build system?

The compiler version is:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50806 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The template is not being instantiated at this time – it is purely the compilation of the template itself that is causing the errors. The error is being generated by this line:

```
`typedef typename Traits::return_type return_type;`

errors in directory d:\tests
d:\ tests\main.cpp(34) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'return_type'
error-continuation d:\tests\main.cpp(35) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Traits' being compiled
d:\ \tests\main.cpp(34) : error C2868: 'Traits::return_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
```

```
template<typename Functor>
struct Traits
{
    enum { Color = 1 };
    typedef decltype(&Functor::operator()) CallOperatorType;
    typedef typename Traits<CallOperatorType>::return_type return_type;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Functor, typename Arg0>
struct Traits<Ret(Functor::*)(Arg0)>
{
    enum { Color = 2 };
    typedef Ret return_type;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Arg0>
struct Traits<Ret (*)(Arg0)>
{
    enum { Color = 3 };
    typedef Ret return_type;
};
```

Comment: If I have understood correctly, vs understands that your typedef is a template-alias, which are not implemented by msvc11. I will try it with other compiler

Comment: There is no line `typedef typename Traits::return_type return_type;` in your current code.